# Arangodb array reduce

Tags: arangodb, aql

Given the following:

```
LET replacements = [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["bar", "baz"]
]

LET title = "foo"

// JS CODE
// title = replacements.reduce((acc, r) => r.replace(acc[0], acc[1]), title);
// or
// for (const r of replacements) {
//   title = title.replace(r[0], r[1]);
// }

RETURN title
```

How is the logic I described with JS possible to implement in aql?

I can't seem to get `FOR` loops to work without returning something, and `LET` itself seems not to allow further reassignment.

Comment: What is your expected result? You want to return the value `'bar'` in this case?

Comment: The expected result is 'baz', as you'd get after the replacements implemented in JS had been executed

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do in pure AQL, you would use Foxx Microservices if you wanted to solve this. LET assignments cannot be changed once made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a case for a user function.

In arangosh:

```js
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> require("@arangodb/aql/functions").register(
    "MYFUNC::REPLACEEQ", 
    function (replacements, title) {
        return replacements.reduce(
                (t, r) => t.replace(r[0], r[1]),
                title
        );
    }
);
```

The AQL-Query:

```
LET replacements = [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["bar", "baz"]
]

RETURN MYFUNC::REPLACEEQ(replacements, "foo")
// => ["baz"]
```